# Angular directive add template on textbox (enter of Spacebar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angular js,My target is to show a html table on (enter of spacebar) in textbox and add the element of the table in that textbox,for that i have written a directive,but i am not sure whether i have done it in right path..Ohk i will show it in detail to be more clear

Here is my html textbox

```
<input type="text" helps ng-model="firstText" code="1">
<div class="col-xs-4 pull-right" helps  donotapply=true></div> //Do i need this??
```

Here `helps` is my directive which binds my html to the div,here is my directive code

```
app.directive('helps', ['$parse', '$http','$filter', function ($parse, $http,$filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'Table.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            console.log(element);
            element.bind("keypress", function (event) {
                    if (event.which === 114 || event.which === 32) {

                        scope.enterMe = function () { // this is to add data to Table

                                scope.newArray = [
                                       {'code' :1,'name' : 'name1','age' : 24},
                                       {'code' : 2,'name' : 'name2','age' : 26},
                                       {'code' : 3,'name' : 'name3','age' : 25}
                                    ]
                            };

                        scope.setElement = function (element) {  // Here set element function is to add my table name to textbox
                            var modelValue = tempattr.ngModel + '_value';
                            var model = $parse(tempattr.ngModel);
                            model.assign(scope, element.name);
                            modelValue = tempattr.ngModel + '_value';
                            modelValue = $parse(modelValue);
                            modelValue.assign(scope, element.code);
                        };
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
}]);
```

And Now here my Table.html

```
<div class="col-xs-4 pull-right" ng-show="hideMyMtHelpDiv">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="search">
    <input type="button" ng-model="gad" value="GO" ng-click="enterMe();">
    <table ng-show="getTableValue" class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover add-lineheight table_scroll">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Code
                </td>
                <td>
                    Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    Age
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="test in newArray" ng-dblclick="setElement(test);">
                <td>
                    {{test.code}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{test.name}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{test.age}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now my question is that, my table is binded with my div as well as my input textbox; So, is there any proper way to do this?

If my question is still unclear kindly comment.
Thank you for any help

Check my plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/lAUyvYKp1weg69CsC2lg?p=preview
and read README

Comment: can you make it as a working  plunker ?

Comment: The code seems legit, but you can also implement it on one input, since you can use restrict: 'A'

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify: you want a table with a text box in one of the cells? Or you want to display a text box and then display a table inside the text box?

Comment: I want to display a table on the spacebar of my textbox

Comment: Hello i have added my plunker please check and help...and read readfile in it.Thanku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are using the save directive in both input and div. You can separate those as first step:

```
mod.directive('onKeydown', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
             setShowSearch: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

             elem.on('keydown', function(event){

                  if (event.which === 114 || event.which === 32) {
                      setShowSearch()(true);
                  }

             });
        }
    };
});
```

Then you can pass a function to set your showSearch variable to that directive and use that on your input:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="firstText" hpcode="1" on-keydown="" set-show-search="setShowSearch"/>
```

Now that `setShowSearch` is living in your `controller` not your `directive` so it has its own `scope`.

```
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.setShowSearch = function(show) {
      //do whatever you want here
  };

  $scope.msg = 'This Must Work!';
}]);
```

Once done you now have a clean directive which is responsible for showing the table and the rest is just passing that array down to that directive in a similar way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: my plunker is working  i just want to isolate my scope,so that so that others cant access my directive scope

Comment: Please check my plunker i am calling this from 2 elements,,please read README in plunker...and can u make a plunker for your solution that will help,thanku

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the workflow here, I am a bit lost

Comment: Ohk press spacebar in the texbox you see,after that press go Button,after that double click on the any one row of the table,now my scope is true here,,so i want isolated scope,so scope should be { },and its not working if my scope is {}...did you get that??

Comment: Maybe I said it wrong, what should happen when you double click any row? should only the search bar get hidden, or should input not get the value of that row or ...

Comment: Its working fine, i just want my scope should be {},and now it should run..but its not working