# Error while directive communication

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-directive

I am getting an error when I included another directive, what I am doing wrong please help.
Here is the error what I am receiving

```
Error:- [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'mthelp', required by directive 'getf', can't be found!
```

My two directive:-

1)

```
app.directive('mthelp', ['$parse', '$http','$filter', function ($parse, $http,$filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'dropDownTable.html',
        controller : function ($scope) {
            console.log(element);
            this.tests = "s";
        }
    }
}]);
```

2)

```
app.directive('getf', function () {
    return {
        require: 'mthelp',
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attr, mthelpCtrl) {
            console.log(element);
            if(event.which === 114 || event.which === 32)
            {
                console.log(mthelpCtrl.tests);

            }
        }
    };
});
```

My html how I am calling them.

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3">FirstName</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" getf ng-model="firstText" hpcode="1">
            </div>
        </div>


  <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right" mthelp  donotapply=true></div>
```

Is there any mistake in this code, can someone help, Thanku?
I am little confuse in this directive thing.

Comment: `require: 'mthelp',` presupposes that getf and mthelp directives belong to the same element. And this isn't so.

Comment: yaa ohk i will do that but the template gets bind with both the element which i dont want?? what should i do for that???

Comment: I'm not sure what 'the template gets bind with both the element' is supposed to mean.

Comment: The html template i am using here is also added inside my input tag..Can you please also check my this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866246/angular-directive-add-template-on-textbox-enter-of-spacebar please i am getting this solution ..Thanku

Comment: ie when i inspect my elements my dropDownTable.html is added in both the elements

Answer (score 0):

try to set it optional like this if you have the case that directive mybe need this directive or maybe not .

```
app.directive('getf', function () {
    return {
        require: '?mthelp', // add ? before directive name 
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attr, mthelpCtrl) {
            console.log(element);
            if(event.which === 114 || event.which === 32)
            {
                console.log(mthelpCtrl.tests);

            }
        }
    };
});
```