# ng-show for multiple value

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

This is my Table

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover add-lineheight table_scroll">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-hide="hidecolumn == key" ng-repeat="(key, value) in localNew[0]">
                    {{key}}
                </th>
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="test in localNew">
                <td ng-hide="hidecolumn == key" ng-repeat="(key, value) in test">
                    {{value}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here `hidecolumn` will hide my column which I don't want to show, e.g. in my controller this is my data:

```
$scope.localNew = [{ 'name': 'name1', 'age': 24, "salary": 2500, "s": 5 }, { 'name': 'name2', 'age': 26, "salary": 2600, "s": 5 }];
```

And this my hide column variable

```
$scope.hidecolumn = "salary";
```

This works fine.

I want to hide multiple columns, so my scope variable will be like

```
$scope.hidecolumn = "name,salary";
```

So how can I manage this in my HTML table to hide multiple columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather use an array instead of a string :

```
$scope.hidecolumns = ['name', 'salary'];
```

and a function to check if the current column should be hide or not :

```
$scope.shouldHideColumn = function(column) {
  if ($scope.hidecolumns.indexOf(column.salary)) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};
```

and then in your `HTML` :

```
<th ng-hide="shouldHideColumn(value)" ng-repeat="(key, value) in localNew[0]">
  {{key}}
</th>
```

Comment: my hidden column is a string ,, it will be comma seperated string,because i have written one directive and this will be passed as attribute to that directive it will hide depending on that directive

Comment: It feels really weird to do that and I'm wondering the use case but ok :)

Comment: can i pass an array attribute to directive

Comment: Of course. You can pass objects too. Just use `=` instead of `@`. It'll give you double data binding. If you want to pass an object with one way data binding use `<`.

Comment: Ohk thanku it solved my question can you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866246/angular-directive-add-template-on-textbox-enter-of-spacebar

Comment: Sorry sir i cant do that, i have a comma seperated string to,which is created by my wizard so i can change that..any other idea how can i do that using comma seperated string??

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array` and its `indexOf` methods :

```
$scope.hidecolumn = [ "name", "salary" ];
```

// View

```
<td ng-hide="hidecolumn.indexOf(key) !== -1" ng-repeat="(key, value) in test">
  {{value}}
</td>
```

Comment: my hiddencolumn is a string ,, it will be comma seperated string,because i have written one directive and this will be passed as attribute to that directive it will hide depending on that directive

Comment: Sorry sir i cant do that, i have a comma seperated string to,which is created by my wizard so i can change that..any other idea how can i do that using comma seperated string??

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this way:

```
<td ng-hide="hidecolumn.indexOf(key) !== -1" ng-repeat="(key, value) in test">
    {{value}}
</td>
```

Comment: will you explain this??

Comment: indexOf method returns -1 if "hidecolumn" string doesn't contain the key.

Comment: my hidden column is a string ,, it will be comma seperated string,because i have written one directive and this will be passed as attribute to that directive it will hide depending on that directive

Comment: Ohk thanku it solved my question can you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866246/angular-directive-add-template-on-textbox-enter-of-spacebar

Comment: Sorry sir i cant do that, i have a comma seperated string to,which is created by my wizard so i can change that..any other idea how can i do that using comma seperated string??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
<td ng-repeat="(key, value) in test" ng-hide="key === 'name' || key === 'salary'">
  {{value}}
</td>
```

Comment: No this i dont want to do if i added another column i need to add that in table also,that i dont want,,,,depending on my scope variable my html table must react dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can call function like:

```
ng-hide="hidecolumn(key)"
```

JS

```
  var hideColumn = function(key) {
    var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    if (fruits.indexOf(key)) === 0 return false;
  }
```

ng-hide will 'hide' element if function return true.

Comment: my hidden column is a string ,, it will be comma seperated string,because i have written one directive and this will be passed as attribute to that directive it will hide depending on that directive

Comment: Ohk thanku it solved my question can you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866246/angular-directive-add-template-on-textbox-enter-of-spacebar

Comment: If it solved your issue could you please vote or mark as correct?

Comment: Sorry sir i cant do that, i have a comma seperated string to,which is created by my wizard so i can change that..any other idea how can i do that using comma seperated string??

Answer (score 0):

indexOf works perfectly fine but if you care about repeating the same approach elsewhere, you might want to create a contains method for array in a global place like this:

```
Array.prototype.contains = function contains(obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] === obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Then create your array:

```
$scope.hiddencolumns = [ "name", "salary" ];
```

Then you simply can use that like this:

```
<td ng-hide="hiddencolumns.contains(key)" ng-repeat="(key, value) in test">
    {{value}}
</td>
```

For converting your comma separated string to array use this:

```
var array = $scope.hidecolumn.split(',');
```

Comment: my hidden column is a string ,, it will be comma seperated string,because i have written one directive and this will be passed as attribute to that directive it will hide depending on that directive  or if can i pass an array in attribute?

Comment: Ohk thanku it solved my question can you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866246/angular-directive-add-template-on-textbox-enter-of-spacebar

Answer (score 0):

I just converted my string to array `var array = string.split(',');` and got the desired result